# How to type tilde in formulas in RMarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am trying to type equations on RMarkdown to create a PDF and I want to use a tilde, how can I go about it. I am trying this but throws back a `pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source ....`

````
---
title: "See"
date: "24 September 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

follows a Bernouli distribution 
$$y_i \~ Bernouli(p_i)$$
````

Comment: In general I would recommend using `\sim` instead of `\~` for denoting distributions.

Comment: @AchimZeileis thanks a big way.. works perfectly

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe if you do

```latex
$$
\sim
$$
```

This should produce the `~` you are attempting to place in your formula.