# Writing tilde(x) as labels in plot function

Tags: r, scatter-plot, tilde

Sorry if its very simple, but I don't know how to write x with a tilde as y axis label in plot function not ggplot2? I tried some codes but did not work at all. Any help?

Comment: Show what you tried, maybe I can help if I see the code

Comment: I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671612/how-to-type-tilde-in-formulas-in-rmarkdown).

Comment: That is not for ggplot, that is for an rMarkdown PDF, they are talking about escaping a tilde. You seem to want to label a plot, but I need to see your code to help you. What I meant before was copy YOUR R CODE (even wrong code) and add it using `{ }` from the tool bar to enclose the code.

Comment: {plot(A~B, data=Rain, xlab=expression('RF'[obs]),ylab ="RF" tilde(x) ,main = "Rainfall(mm)")

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the unquoted `?plotmath` expression in `expression`, whether in ggplot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame()) + ylab(expression(tilde(x)))
```

[image]

or base R:

```r
plot(1, ylab = expression(tilde(x)))
```

[image]